# Aggregation in R to calculate percentage of total by group?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

```
DDD <- summarise(
  group_by(Customers, Last_region, Last_state, Last_city),     
  Count = length(Last_city),
  Total = sum(Customer.Value, na.rm = TRUE),
  Percent = sum(Customer.Value * 100 / sum(Customer.Value, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

I have tried this code.I get the group by for total & count but not for percent ?

Comment: @akrun Did you overwrite the code on purpose?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach  Sorry, I didn't get you.  Why should I do that on purpose?  I didn't do anything except made the code formatted.  You can look at the edit history

Comment: @akrun You copied in the code from the linked post, checking the revision history the code was very different.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach My comment to your response got somehow deleted.  Yes, when I formatted it, I copied the wrong one.  Sorry for that.  I am not sure who is deleting a genuine response.  It seems like somebody want to show I did it purposefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to change to `Customers$Customer.Value` and also for better understanding, use the `%>%` instead of using nested functions.

```
Customers %>%    
   group_by(Last_region, Last_state, Last_city) %>%     
   summarise(Count = length(Last_city),
             Total = sum(Customer.Value, na.rm = TRUE),
             Percent = sum(Customer.Value * 100 / 
                          sum(Customers$Customer.Value, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

As the OP didn't show any reproducible example, we also have a doubt of the closing bracket in `sum(Customer.Value*100`